# String read in from file not responding to string manipulation

Tags: string, perl, file-io

I have a Perl subroutine that creates a file, like so:

```
sub createFile {
    if (open (OUTFILEHANDLE, ">$fileName")) {
        print OUTFILEHANDLE "$desiredVariable\n";
    }
    close(OUTFILEHANDLE);
}
```

where $fileName and $desiredVariable have been previously defined. I call that, and then call the following subroutine, which reads from the file, takes the first (only) line, and saves it into the variable $desiredVariable:

```
sub getInfoFromFile {
    if (existFile($fileName)) {
        if (open (READFILEHANDLE, "<$fileName")) {
            my @entire_file=<READFILEHANDLE>; # Slurp
            $desiredVariable = $entire_file[0];
            chop $desiredVariable;
            close(READFILEHANDLE);
        }
    }
}
```

If I leave out the "chop" line, $desiredVariable is what I want, but with a trailing <strike>space</strike> newline. If I include the "chop" line, $desiredVariable is an empty string. For some reason, "chop" is killing the whole string. I've tried it with `$desiredVariable =~ s/\s*$//;` and several other string manipulation tricks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you really mean a trailing *space*, not a trailing *newline*?

Comment: It would help to see the input you're using and the expected output.

Comment: It might be easier to read just the first line: `$desiredVariable = <READFILEHANDLE>;`.

Comment: Does `$entire_file[0]` end with `\r\n`?

Comment: Also, is `$fileName` in `createFile` the same variable as `$fileName` in `getInfoFromFile`? Global variables, global filehandles, and two-argument `open` calls are not best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you included does not reproduce the problem. I'm guessing it was lost in translation somehow while you were anonymizing it. I ran the script as follows, the only adjustment I made was `-f` instead of `existsFile()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub createFile {
    if (open (OUTFILEHANDLE, ">$fileName")) {
        print OUTFILEHANDLE "$desiredVariable\n";
    }
    close(OUTFILEHANDLE);
}

sub getInfoFromFile {
    if (-f $fileName) {
        if (open (READFILEHANDLE, "<$fileName")) {
            my @entire_file=<READFILEHANDLE>; # Slurp
            $desiredVariable = $entire_file[0];
            chop $desiredVariable;
            close(READFILEHANDLE);
        }
    }
}

$fileName = "test.txt";
$desiredVariable = "Hello World!";

createFile();
$desiredVariable = "";
getInfoFromFile();

print "Got '$desiredVariable'\n"; # Got 'Hello World!'
```